# verifyPhoneNumber does not send SMS message in Firebase phone Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Within my app I am calling the verifyPhoneNumber method to send the user the SMS verification code. I then push another view controller that contains the code to verify the SMS sent to the user. The method returns no error and a valid id. Also in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I am receiving the 'silent' notification from Firebase, however, the user never is receiving an SMS message. What is going wrong? I am not using the simulator and am using a valid device. Any help is greatly appreciated! Cheers

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+\(currentCallingCountry.number) \(enteredNumber!)", uiDelegate: nil)
    { (id, error) in
        UserDefaults.standard.set(id, forKey: "authVerificationID")

        if error != nil
        {
            print(error)

            return
        }

        print(id)
        print(error)
    }

    let verificationController = NumberVerificationViewController()

    verificationController.number = enteredNumber

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(verificationController, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include the country's code when you put the number in, if not then you won't get an SMS verification text message. If you were in the US, you should put +1, the three digit area code, and the rest of the phone number. For example, +11234567899.

Comment: Formatting is just as you mention and still no luck